# How do I split a list of a single string containing multiple numbers into a list of separated integers?

Tags: python, list

Sorry, I'm a complete beginner and I couldn't find a lot of information on Google.

For my assignment, I need to read the contents I've generated in a file and only output the values that are more than 20 but less than 50. I have the file generated, when I read the file and print the contents all the numbers show up as a single string value in a list:

```
['11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31']
```

I've removed the commas so it shows up

```
['11 24 62 59 1 28 61 5 54 38 31']
```

I've been searching around but I can't find something for my exact issue.

This is my code:

```
import os

file_path = ("/Users/elian/Desktop/School/Scripting/Week 5/")
os.chdir(file_path)
file_name = ("Lab5.txt")

with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
    contents = file.readlines() # Reads the contents of the file, outputs as a list.
    print(type(contents)) # class 'list'
    contents = ' '.join(str(contents).split(',')) # Removes commas
    print(type(contents)) # class 'str'
```

I've tried using split() but it seems to just make everything worse.

Edit:

This is the source code for the number generator this file is reading from:

```
import os
import random
# Set the file name
file_name = input("Please input your desired file name: ")
# Change the working directory
file_path = input("Please input the file path where this file is to be saved in: ") 
os.chdir(file_path)
# Asks the user how many numbers they would like to generate. 
num_of_values = int(input("How many random numbers would you like generated: "))
with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    for i in range(1, num_of_values + 1):
        random_raw=random.randrange(0,100)
        random_final=int(random_raw)
        file.write
        # convert to a string for the file write
        num_string=str(random_final)
        print(i)
        if i < num_of_values:
            num_string= num_string + ","            
        file.write(num_string)

# Close the file - OS can have issues with files that are not closed
file.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You say you generated the file, so show that code as well. There are better ways to write that data to a file for easier read back and parsing

Comment: Please show the output of `print(contents)` right after `contents = file.readlines()`.

Comment: The output of print(contents) is: `['11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31']`

I've also added the code for the generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to find round tens, you can use a regex:

```
l = ['11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31']

import re

out = ','.join(re.findall(r'\b[234]\d\b', l[0]))
```

output: `'24,28,38,31'`

regex:

```
\b        # word boundary
[234]\d   # 2 digit number starting with 2 or 3 or 4
`b        # word boundary
```

##### excluding the lower bound:

```
l = ['11,20,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31']  ## added 20 to the list

import re

','.join(re.findall(r'\b(2[1-9]|[34]\d)\b', l[0]))
```

output: `'24,28,38,31'`

regex:

```
\b        # word boundary
(         # start group
2[1-9]    # 2 digit number starting with 2 and ending in 1-9
|         # OR
[34]\d    # 2 digit number starting with 3 or 4
)         # end group
`b        # word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple pythonic way:

```py
l = '11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31'
x = [i for i in l.split(",") if 20 < int(i) < 50]
print(x)
# ['24', '28', '38', '31']
```

Comment: When I add this to my code I'm getting a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['11" error

Comment: @ElianManzueta add the input data to the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string always has this exact form:

```
list_string_in_list = ['11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31'] 
valid_int_list = [int(i) for i in list_string_in_list[0].split(",") if 20 < int(i) < 50]
```

Or if you prefer using loops:

```
list_string_in_list = ['11,24,62,59,1,28,61,5,54,38,31']
valid_int_list = []
for number in list_string_in_list[0].split(","):
    number_as_int = int(number)
    if 20 < number_as_int < 50:
        valid_int_list.append(number_as_int)
```

However it is very likely that how you construct this list is wrong in the first place. If you iterate over something and create this list, why do you append it into one long string inside the list? It might make more sense to use `.append()` to fill that list in the first place.

Edit: It seems like this format is given in the file you are reading. So just parsing it as a string and then splitting is the right way to do it.

Comment: Yea it's reading from a random number generator. It generates numbers from 0 to 100 and then adds commas to make the text file more readable. I'm not sure why the list is that way, it's just how my teacher made it

Comment: @Elian If your teacher wrote that generator code you added get a new teacher

Answer (score 0):

To write the file more efficiently:

```py
import random

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    num_list = random.choices(range(100), k=11)
    num_string = ','.join(str(n) for n in num_list)
    file.write(num_string)
```

Or if allowed to use the `csv` module:

```py
import random
import csv

with open('test.txt', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    num_list = random.choices(range(100), k=11)
    writer.writerow(num_list)
```

To read the file:

```py
with open('test.txt') as file:
    contents = [int(n) for n in file.read().strip().split(',')]

print(contents)
```

Or with the `csv` module:

```py
import csv

with open('test.txt', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        contents = [int(n) for n in line]
        print(contents)
```